# Agrupar en columnas un listado de un checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap

como estan?
Se me esta presentando un pequeño problema y quería ver si pueden ayudarme a solucionarlo.
Tengo una parte del código que genera un listado de checkbox a partir de una consulta en sql y un while para recorrerlo.

```
 <div  id='DivPai' style="display: none;">


            <label for="validationDefaultUsername" class="form-label">MATERIAS</label>
            <?php
            $sqlClientes = ("SELECT * FROM `tabla_materias`");
            $queryData   = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlClientes);
            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($queryData)) { ?>

                <div class="form-check col-sm-6" id='DivP'>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $data['COD_MATERIA']; ?>" id="flexCheckDefault" name="materia_elegida[]">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                        <?php echo $data['MATERIA']; ?>
                    </label>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

El problema que tengo es que esto me genera un listado un poco extenso, y quería al menos dividirlo en dos columnas, si pudieran ser 3 o 4, mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ALguna sugerencia??? desde ya, muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Asumiendo un número desconocido y variable del total de registros, obtendría el total de registros, determinaría un total de registros por columna y con un contador y un if dentro del while, prepararía los div's para cada columna.

Comment: Si tienes bootstrap puedes usar la clase row y col para estructurar tu html

Answer (score 0):

Muchas Gracias! lo resolvi como me dijeron creando columnas dentro de un row y replicando la consulta según lo que quería mostrar en cada uno de ellos.